# Testing for random values with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a method in one of my models that returns a random row

```
Intention.offset(rand(Intention.count)).first
```

It works fine, but how can I test it with Rspec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your code:

```
Kernel.rand(Intention.count)
```

and in your spec:

```
let(:intention_count) { 3 }

Intention.stub(:count).and_return(intention_count)
Kernel.stub(:rand).with(intention_count).and_return(0) # will return 0
```

Basically, we are calling rand using the `Kernel` class to be able to `stub` that method to return what we want.